# Encog, save to file trained network

Tags: java, encog

Is it possible to save a trained network to a file, then to use it again (to load file)? You can give a simple example? Currently I should run every time training:

EncogUtility.trainConsole (network, trainingSet, TRAINING_MINUTES)

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this to save the trained network file (this is C#, Java may have a different class for FileInfo):

```
FileInfo networkFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Data\network.eg");
Encog.Persist.EncogDirectoryPersistence.SaveObject(networkFile, (BasicNetwork)network);
```

You can then use something like this to reload the network file:

```
network = (BasicNetwork)(Encog.Persist.EncogDirectoryPersistence.LoadObject(networkFile));
```

Comment: Appreciate this is was posted a long time ago now, but would appreciate if someone could shed some light on this. I get the following error when running the above: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key 'Encog.Neural.NEAT.NEATNetwork' was not present in the dictionary.' Is there a simple way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Use this example to save/load your network:

```
import static org.encog.persist.EncogDirectoryPersistence.*;

String filename = "C:/tmp/network.eg";

// save network...
saveObject(new File(filename), network);

// load network...
BasicNetwork loadFromFileNetwork = (BasicNetwork) loadObject(new File(filename));
```

**Source:** [https://github.com/encog](https://github.com/encog/encog-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/encog/examples/neural/persist/EncogPersistence.java#L73)